# c# wpf Combox value in editable field must be different that displaymemberpath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a Combobox with a concate string in displaymemberpath ('DescriptionComplete' in code-behind below), and that is what i get in the editable field BUT this is only the IdEchantillon that i want into the editable field...
How must i do please ?

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbEchantillon" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEchantillon.IdEchantillon}" ItemsSource="{Binding OcEchantillon}" DisplayMemberPath="DescriptionComplete" SelectedValuePath="IdEchantillon" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentEchantillon}" Text="{Binding IdEchantillon}" IsEditable="True" Width="355" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Courier New" SelectionChanged="cbEchantillon_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```
public class Echantillon : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _IdEchantillon;
        private string _Description;
        private DateTime _dateechan;
        private string _descriptionComplete;
}
    public string IdEchantillon
    {
        get { return _IdEchantillon; }
        set { _IdEchantillon = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IdEchantillon"); }
    }


    public string Description
    {
        get { return _Description; }
        set { _Description = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Description"); }
    }

    public DateTime Dateechan
    {
        get { return _dateechan; }
        set { _dateechan = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Dateechan"); }
    }

    public string DescriptionComplete
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", IdEchantillon.PadRight(20), Dateechan.ToShortDateString(), Description); }
        set { _descriptionComplete = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Just try to explain it step by step, if you're not very good at English, just do it step by step. Don't try to shorten your words, it's hard to understand what you actually want here.

Answer (score 1):

At first, please, cleanup your ComboBox property bindings. You should not create binding for `SelectedValue`, because you already have binding for `SelectedItem` property. The `SelectedValue` is determined by extracting the value by `SelectedValuePath` from the `SelectedItem`.

In case of binding to ViewModel, you should not also bind `Text` property. Use `ItemsSource` as you do, and set `DisplayMemberPath` property to what you want to show as the text representation of the every item in the bound collection.